# Writing User ObjectID to variable #Powershell

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, properties

I am looking to find a way to write the Object ID of a user to a variable automatically via AzureAD.

> Get-AzureAdUser -ObjectId "Contose@contoso.com"

will give the output of the ObjectId, DisplayName, UPN, UserType

I am looking to the write the ObjectId of the user (e.g qwert_1232_trwwqe) to variable such as $UserId for use further in the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lee Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) provides a good pointer:

> the usual way is to keep things in the `$Var` and simply address the properties when needed. So, assign the call to a `$Var` and get the value with `$Var.ObjectID`.

That said, **if you do want to store the object ID *alone* in a *dedicated variable*, simply access the `.ObjectId` property on the object returned by `Get-AzureAdUser`**:

```sh
$userId = (Get-AzureAdUser -ObjectId 'Contose@contoso.com').ObjectId
```

---

In a follow-up comment you mention arriving at:

```sh
$Var = Get-AzureAdUser -ObjectId "Contose@contoso.com" | Select ObjectId
```

However, this use of the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet (whose built-in alias is `select`) is virtually pointless, as this still returns a (new, custom) *object* that requires you to access its `.ObjectId` *property* in order to retrieve the object ID value - and for that you could have just assigned the object returned by `Get-AzureAdUser` *directly* to `$Var`, as Lee suggests.

**It *is* possible to use `Select-Object` to extract a single property *value***, namely **via the 
`-ExpandProperty <propertyName>` parameter**:

```sh
$Var = Get-AzureAdUser -ObjectId 'Contose@contoso.com' | Select -ExpandProperty ObjectId
```

However, the **`(...).ObjectId` syntax (*dot notation*)** is not only ***more convenient*, but also *faster*** - and it **even works on *multiple* objects (in PSv3+)**, in which case an *array* of values is returned (a feature called [*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)).

In short, **`Select-Object -ExpandProperty` is only needed if you're processing *very large* collections that must be processed *one by one* in the pipeline**.